# Некорректное восстановление сервиса

Tags: android, android-service

Создаю процесс, который должен опять запускаться после того, как его убили:

```
package com.vitaliy.backgroundservice;


import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class BackgroundService extends Service{

    private final String LOG = "MY_BACKGROUND_SERVICE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG, "onStartComand " + "name: " + intent.getStringExtra("name"));
        readFlag(flags);
        MyRun myRun = new MyRun(startId);
        new Thread(myRun).start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    private void readFlag(int flag){
        switch (flag){
            case START_FLAG_REDELIVERY: {
                Log.d(LOG, "START_FLAG_REDELIVERY");
                break;
            }
            case START_FLAG_RETRY: {
                Log.d(LOG, "START_FLAG_RETRY");
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    class MyRun implements Runnable{

        private int startId;

        public MyRun(int startId){
            this.startId = startId;
            Log.d(LOG, "MyRun# " + startId + " create");
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(LOG, "MyRun# " + startId);
            try{
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            }catch (InterruptedException ie){
                ie.getStackTrace();
            }
            stop();
        }


        private void stop(){
            Log.d(LOG, "MyRun# " + startId + " end, stoped = " + stopSelfResult(startId) );
        }

    }

}
```

Работает и даже после остановки опять начинает работать, но только доходит до метода onCreate и вылетает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В чем может быть ошибка ?**

Comment: Как запускаете? Логи ошибки? Что такое MyRun?

Comment: @VAndrJ, запускаю из другого активити, через неявный интент. MyRun - это просто отдельный поток в котором выполняется задержка выполнения , печатаются логи и все ...

Comment: @VAndrJ, но при возврате START_REDELIVER_INTENT, никаких ошибок не возникает и все работает нормально ...